# Accessing streaming bluetooth data on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, bluetooth, live-streaming

I am currently writing an app using XCode that will allow the streaming of medical data to the app. Using the Alive Heart Monitor which streams live heartbeats over bluetooth spp, I want to be able to receive those live streams into my app.

Currently, I am not able to discover the AHM device and am not sure about how to go about receiving the live stream.

Is there any way to do this?

I've seen this article: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954, however it seems to only work between 2 iPad/iPhones. I want to be able to just receive the live stream from a non-iOS device.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have consulted with developers on Apple forums and was made aware that this was not possible as iPad does not have support for the bluetooth SPP profile.